# How to mock nested requests?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I'm trying to create unit test ans mock it with sinon. Here is my simple app:

```
var request = require('request');

var MY_CLASS = {
    getData: function (req, res, next) {
        return request.get({
            uri: 'https://xxxx.xxxx.com',
        }, function (error, data) {
            if (error) {
                return next(error, null);
            }

            request.get({
                uri: `https://yyyy.yyyy.com/${data.id}`,
            }, function (error, data) {
                if (error) {
                    return next(error, null);
                }

                return next(null, data);
            });
        });
    }
};

module.exports = MY_CLASS;
```

Now, how do I properly mock each request in my test suite for `getData` function? Seems this one will mock both `xxxx.com` and `yyyy.com`. In other words I want to mock different response for each one

```
before(()=>{
    sinon
    .stub(request, 'get')
    .yields(null, {statusCode: 200, id: 10});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could you [`onFirstCall`, `onSecondCall`, `onCall(n)`](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/stubs/) etc to implement the behavior.

```
before(()=>{
    sinon
    .stub(request, 'get')
      .onFirstCall().yields(null, {statusCode: 200, id: 10})
      .onSecondCall().yields(null, {statusCode: 200, id: 11}};
});
```

Ultimately you could use `callsFake(fn)` that implements whatever logic you need.